# Add multiple child nodes to xml using xpath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, xdoc

I have a xml like below

```
<ProcessInvoice>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <CreationDateTime>2016-06-01 13:15:36</CreationDateTime>
    <ApplicationGroup>BBEX</ApplicationGroup>
    <MessageType>PROCESSINVOICE</MessageType>
  </ApplicationArea>
</ProcessInvoice>
```

Now I have path and value to add, but it is dynamic.
It can be like following

```
path-/ProcessInvoice/ApplicationArea/UserArea/Sample1 
value-001

path-/ProcessInvoice/ApplicationArea/UserArea/UserAreaLine/Sample1 
value-002
```

if the path is present then i have to add the value, else modify the value.

I can split the path and loop through to find till what node is present and what i have to add but I think there might be more elegant way of doing this.Please help me with the best approach to solve this?

Edit
Note- I will prefer XDocument And XElement.

May be I didnt explain properly.
My xml and node path both are dynamic.
There might be situation where multiple nodes are missing from my xml.
Now problem is i need to identify upto which node is existing in xml and which nodes i need to create.

Thanks

Comment: for every "UserArea" or "UserArea/UserAreaLine" there is only one "Sample1" node?

Comment: yes thats true. for now we will have only one node.

Comment: the "Sample1" node always exist?

Answer (score 0):

If "Sample1" node always exist, the code will look like this:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FILE);
    var userArea = DocumentElement["ProcessInvoice"]["ApplicationArea"]["UserArea"];

    foreach (XmlNode element in userArea.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (element.Name== "Sample1" )
        {
            XmlNode node == element;
            node.InnerText ="001";
        }
        else if (element.Name == "UserAreaLine")
        {
            XmlNode node == element["Sample1"];
            node.InnerText ="002";
        }

    }
```